# Does Android allow users to supply their own fonts?

Tags: android, fonts

I created an Android app that includes custom fonts (i.e., Google Fonts).  I include these by adding them to the APK at build time.  However, I would like to allow users to supply their own TTF files at run-time in order to add greater flexibility to my app. Is this possible?  If so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your text is being rendered by Java code, [use `Typeface.createFromFile()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html#createFromFile(java.io.File)) instead of whatever you are presently using (e.g., `Typeface.createFromAsset()`). This only works with files on the filesystem that you can reach. If you have a `Uri` to the font (e.g., from `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`), you will need to make a local copy of the font file (e.g., on [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html)).

If your text is being rendered by `WebView`, you should be able to add CSS rules that point to a font located on the filesystem, though I have not tried this. It's even possible that CSS could use a `content://` `Uri` like you get from `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, though I am skeptical that this will work.